# Can not use pip to install ipython in mac

Tags: python, macos, pip, ipython

When I use pip to install ipython in my mac, I meet a trouble,

```
➜  ~ sudo easy_install pip
Searching for pip
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Best match: pip 8.1.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/41/27/9a8d24e1b55bd8c85e4d022da2922cb206f183e2d18fee4e320c9547e751/pip-8.1.1.tar.gz#md5=6b86f11841e89c8241d689956ba99ed7
Processing pip-8.1.1.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-gX8Ewd/pip-8.1.1/setup.cfg
Running pip-8.1.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-gX8Ewd/pip-8.1.1/egg-dist-tmp-MjRQzD
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.mailmap'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'pip/_vendor/Makefile'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'dev-requirements.txt'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'
no previously-included directories found matching '.github'
no previously-included directories found matching '.travis'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
no previously-included directories found matching 'contrib'
no previously-included directories found matching 'tasks'
no previously-included directories found matching 'tests'
Adding pip 8.1.1 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip2.7 script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip2 script to /usr/local/bin

Installed /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
➜  ~ pip install ipython
Collecting ipython
  Downloading ipython-4.2.0-py2-none-any.whl (736kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 737kB 1.1MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): traitlets in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pickleshare in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): simplegeneric>0.8 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): backports.shutil-get-terminal-size in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): decorator in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Collecting setuptools>=18.5 (from ipython)
  Downloading setuptools-21.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (509kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 512kB 2.9MB/s 
Collecting gnureadline (from ipython)
  Downloading gnureadline-6.3.3-cp27-none-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (132kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 4.9MB/s 
Collecting appnope (from ipython)
  Downloading appnope-0.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pexpect (from ipython)
  Downloading pexpect-4.0.1.tar.gz (143kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 153kB 66kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipython-genutils in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from traitlets->ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pathlib2 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pickleshare->ipython)
Collecting ptyprocess>=0.5 (from pexpect->ipython)
  Downloading ptyprocess-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from pathlib2->pickleshare->ipython)
Installing collected packages: setuptools, gnureadline, appnope, ptyprocess, pexpect, ipython
  Found existing installation: setuptools 1.1.6
    Uninstalling setuptools-1.1.6:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 726, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 746, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 299, in move
    copytree(src, real_dst, symlinks=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 208, in copytree
    raise Error, errors
Error: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', '/var/folders/rv/61031cn16tbcxv3brgsd7sn80000gn/T/pip-0QWsTT-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/rv/61031cn16tbcxv3brgsd7sn80000gn/T/pip-0QWsTT-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', '/var/folders/rv/61031cn16tbcxv3brgsd7sn80000gn/T/pip-0QWsTT-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/rv/61031cn16tbcxv3brgsd7sn80000gn/T/pip-0QWsTT-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', '/var/folders/rv/61031cn16tbcxv3brgsd7sn80000gn/T/pip-0QWsTT-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/rv/61031cn16tbcxv3brgsd7sn80000gn/T/pip-0QWsTT-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', '/var/folders/rv/61031cn16tbcxv3brgsd7sn80000gn/T/pip-0QWsTT-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/rv/61031cn16tbcxv3brgsd7sn80000gn/T/pip-0QWsTT-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', '/var/folders/rv/61031cn16tbcxv3brgsd7sn80000gn/T/pip-0QWsTT-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/rv/61031cn16tbcxv3brgsd7sn80000gn/T/pip-0QWsTT-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib'")]
```

While I uninstall pip,

```
➜  ~ sudo pip uninstall pip
Password:
The directory '/Users/Li/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Uninstalling pip-8.1.1:
  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg
  /usr/local/bin/pip
  /usr/local/bin/pip2
  /usr/local/bin/pip2.7
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled pip-8.1.1
The directory '/Users/Li/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
```

Dose anyone know the reason and how can I install ipython? I use python2.7 which installed by mac.

...I have to add some words...because stackoverflow said my code is too much while my words too few...

With the sudo -H command, I tried:

```
➜  ~ sudo -H pip install ipython
Collecting ipython
  Using cached ipython-4.2.0-py2-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): traitlets in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pickleshare in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): simplegeneric>0.8 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): backports.shutil-get-terminal-size in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): decorator in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Collecting setuptools>=18.5 (from ipython)
  Using cached setuptools-21.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting gnureadline (from ipython)
  Using cached gnureadline-6.3.3-cp27-none-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
Collecting appnope (from ipython)
  Using cached appnope-0.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pexpect (from ipython)
  Using cached pexpect-4.0.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipython-genutils in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from traitlets->ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pathlib2 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pickleshare->ipython)
Collecting ptyprocess>=0.5 (from pexpect->ipython)
  Using cached ptyprocess-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from pathlib2->pickleshare->ipython)
Installing collected packages: setuptools, gnureadline, appnope, ptyprocess, pexpect, ipython
  Found existing installation: setuptools 1.1.6
    Uninstalling setuptools-1.1.6:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 726, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 746, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 299, in move
    copytree(src, real_dst, symlinks=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 208, in copytree
    raise Error, errors
Error: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', '/tmp/pip-Nqp6JH-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-Nqp6JH-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', '/tmp/pip-Nqp6JH-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-Nqp6JH-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', '/tmp/pip-Nqp6JH-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-Nqp6JH-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', '/tmp/pip-Nqp6JH-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-Nqp6JH-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', '/tmp/pip-Nqp6JH-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-Nqp6JH-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib'")]
```

Comment: I don't see what the problem is or what you're even asking. You installed pip and ipython and uninstalled... that's it. Usually if you want to use a pip installed python module then you should leave it installed.

Comment: Hi, the problem is that the ipython can not be installed, as the end of ipython installation, there is a error.

Comment: It was already installed. The error was related to setuptools, also it mentioned `If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.`

Comment: but when I type ipython, the shell said command not find, before I uninstall pip...

Comment: I would strongly recommend to do this in a virtual environment. You are modifying the system library of OS X. There are services that depend on a stable python environment - modifying the system library may prevent those from working.

Comment: You should be showing that information in your question.

Comment: Thanks for I'L'I , I tried what you said, but it's also not work.

Comment: when installing with pip you'll need to use "sudo pip install ...", otherwise pip won't be allowed to properly install modules on OS X.

Comment: For Juice, sorry I don't get it. I never use a virtual environment. When I use Ubuntu, It seems that ubuntu will automatically modify the library for me.

Comment: Also don't install pip with easy_install... use the instructions on this page: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: Thanks and I tried it but still wrong. Maybe it's not a pip or ipython problem. I find my PYTHONPATH also do don't work( I write it in .bash_profile) while my other path works well. It's wired. I am finding the reason.

Comment: You should add the additional info / output to your question since it might be relevant.

Comment: I don't know why, but when I give up it and use brew to install python and pip, and using this pip to install ipython... it's okay. I think maybe the reason is that the mac do not treat software installation path good ( while in Linux , I don't meet this trouble..) . Anyway, Thanks a lot!